# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un botón en Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Estoy utilizando esta instrucción para cambiar el color cuando se corra la app

```
boton.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
```

Pero, ¿cómo puedo hacer si quiero cambiar por un código de color? Por ejemplo `#0040FF` en lugar de `blue`.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con

```
new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x0040FF));
```

Comment: no me sirvió esto, lo resolví de esta manera 
b1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));_cursiva_**negrita** 'b1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));'